# How to remove first letter in Appendix list for ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'v been trying to find a solution for this problem for the last couple of days. A variety of things I've tried haven't worked.

What I need: I want to remove the first letter that is generated in the Table of Contents for the Appendix. At present it states "A Appendix A"

[image]

I want the word "Appendix" to be left aligned with the numbers. Here is  quick mock up in Word.

[image]

I also have items and lsitings grouped under each appendix by using

```
\chapter{Appendix A}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}
```

and so I'd like to keep this. I am using the report class.

Comment: You can do it manually with a starred chapter, i.e., `\chapter*{Appendix A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}`

Comment: `\chapter{Appendix A}` is your error you should just use `\chapter{Appendix}` the section number is applied automatically (you can customise that to be Appendix A rather than A Appendix just as you customise \section headings.)

Comment: In other words: You should never number chapters/appendices manually. Instead you should configure the headings to show what you want. BTW: You are using semantic chapter titles like “Conclusion”. So I would recommend to also use semantic appendix titles. They would be much more useful than just “Appendix” with a (alphabetic) number.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand that, but that isn't my problem at all. My problem is the pre-fix of "A"

Comment: but you defined `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}` so naturally you get a prefix of A.  You would not get that by default